# Hibernate not setting foreign key on insert

Tags: hibernate, orm, foreign-keys, mapping, reverse-engineering

I have Many-to-one relationship and when I'm trying to insert a value, the foreigh key is not passed. The hibernate doesn't include it's values in the generated SQL query.

Definition of City and LocalizedLocation entities:

```
<!-- LocalizedLocation -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="servicedb.dal.domain.LocalizedLocation" table="localized_location" catalog="DB">
     <composite-id name="id" class="servicedb.dal.domain.LocalizedLocationId">
     <key-property name="localeId" type="int">
       <column name="locale_id" />
     </key-property>
     <key-property name="locationId" type="int">
       <column name="location_id" />
     </key-property>
     </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="location" class="servicedbcedb.dal.domain.Location" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
   <column name="location_id" not-null="true" />
 </many-to-one>
 <many-to-one name="city" class="servicedb.dal.domain.City" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
     <column name="locale_id" not-null="true" />
     <column name="country_code" length="2" not-null="true" />
     <column name="city_id" not-null="true" />
     </many-to-one>    
        <property name="title" type="string">
     <column name="title" length="120" />
     </property>
   </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>

 <!-- City -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="servicedb.dal.domain.City" table="city" catalog="DB">
     <composite-id name="id" class="servicedb.dal.domain.CityId">
     <key-property name="localeId" type="int">
       <column name="locale_id" />
     </key-property>
     <key-property name="countryCode" type="string">
       <column name="country_code" length="2" />
     </key-property>
     <key-property name="id" type="int">
       <column name="id" />
     </key-property>
     </composite-id>
     <property name="name" type="string">
     <column name="name" length="100" not-null="true" />
     </property>
     <set name="localizedLocations" table="localized_location" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
     <key>
       <column name="locale_id" not-null="true" />
       <column name="country_code" length="2" not-null="true" />
       <column name="city_id" not-null="true" />
     </key>
     <one-to-many class="servicedb.dal.domain.LocalizedLocation" />
     </set>
   </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

The following code should insert Location and then LocalizedLocation, the LocalizedLocation should have the foreign key pointing to the inserted Location, but for some reason it doesn't.

```
Session session = locationDAO.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();

// Location inititalization, the object is correctly populated
session.save(location);

LocalizedLocation localizedLocation = new LocalizedLocation();
localizedLocation.setId(new LocalizedLocationId(locale.getId(), location.getId()));

localizedLocation.setCity(city); // the city already exists on the database, object is not null
localizedLocation.setLocale(locale); // the locale already exusts on the database
localizedLocation.setLocation(location);

session.save(localizedLocation);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

After the commit, the generated insert query is the following:

```
insert into DB.localized_location (title, description, locale_id, location_id)  values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

But it should be:

```
insert into DB.localized_location (title, description, locale_id, location_id, city_id, country_code)  values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Does anybody know why the foreign key to the city table is not included in the generated sql insert statement?

I'm also using the eclipse and reveng.xml to reverse engineer the database, so my hbm files are auto generated and I'm not using EJB3 annotations.

Comment: Help @JoshC. I was trying to reuse the locale_id by multiple table attributes. I don't know why the Hibernate didn't like it, but for some reason it was not populating the FK's on insertion. To solve this issue, I've created an additional attribute for the LocaleId. So, the locale_id has remained as a PK for Location Table, and the additional attribute locale_city_id became the FK of the City Table. Both attributes has always the same value (this is insured by the DAL logic). With the described approach you'll have redundant information on your DB, I don't know if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your *city* property in LocalizedLocation mapping seems to have "insert=false" and "update=false". Mapped this way, it makes this an "inverse" relationship, in which the connection is only saved from the other side - i.e. while saving the Location.

Either remove those two attributes, or save the city after setting up the relationship on its side.

*Edit*: corrected the property.

BTW, in case the city does not map a list of LocalizedLocations - as i somehow got this idea from your description - it does not seem to make sense to have those two properties at false since the only way to insert that relationship would be mapping another property on the same column (or doing it directly on the db).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your suggestion. The location_id is published correctly, the missing values are the city_id and the country_code from the localized_location.

Comment: Sorry about that, i misplaced the property names, but the same concept applies to _city_, since you have "update" and "create" at *false* there as well. I'll update the answer for clarity, but the suggestion is pretty much the same, only on the "city" relationship.

Comment: I've trying both ways, removing the insert and update attributes and saving the City after setting up the relationship. But the foreign key is still missing.

Comment: BTW, when remove both "update" and "create" attributes, I'm getting the following exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: guideme.servicedb.dal.domain.LocalizedLocation column: locale_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")